# Why does my model perform better when I use a Spacy pretrained pipeline without word vectors?

Tags: nlp, vectorization, spacy

My model performs better (higher accuracy, precision, recall) when I train it using Spacy's smallest pretrained pipeline, `en_core_web_sm`. When I train it using Spacy's `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg`, it struggles to reach a measly 70% accuracy. With `en_core_web_sm`, it reaches 91% accuracy with much smaller loss scores.

I modified training data several times to improve accuracy and reliability. I am confident that my training data does not contain any outliers or incorrectly labelled entries. Regardless of the state of my training data and the initial learning rate, the only way I could improve my accuracy score was to revert to the `en_core_web_sm` pipeline.

My training data is syntactically simple. It is not verbose but does contain out-of-vocabulary words that are unique to my data.